# How to purge large volume of data in DB2 without affecting the application performance?

Tags: database, db2

Please let me kow the efficient way of purging the data from transaction database without affecting the application performance.

Comment: So far I tried to delete all the records that satisfies the purge condition. The no of records that needs to be deleted is in millions and it takes more tiem to delete and somtimes deadlock occurs as the same table is being accessed via webapplication. For eg, deleting 100 records took more than 1 hr to get deleted.

Comment: Please show your code, some sample data, and tell us the size of the tables in question..  It is quite unusual (to say the least) that deleting 100 records would take more than an hour.

Comment: There is nothing unusual with the code, it's just  a simple delete statement with in clause. The problem was the same table was actively used by the online web application hence deadlock acquired. I would like to know the best way to delete the rows without impacting the existing web applications.

Comment: I have downvoted this question because you have not taken the time to adequately describe your problem.  Sample code is almost always a good idea, even in mundane cases.  At least write a detailed description of what you are trying to do, the structure of your database/site, and the specifics of the problem.  If you want people to spend time helping you, you need to spend time asking the question properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the alter table command to empty a table with "not logged inittialy"

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r1/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000888.html

You can also use the Truncate command

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r1/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0053474.html

If you need to do this operation for several tables, you can generate the queries for delete the rows by querying the catalog.